# How works a loop device (especially a mounted OS Image)

Tags: kernel, filesystem, ubuntu-for-android

I know, it's a often asked question on many boards and I have **read** the wikipedia article. But those articles aren't satisfactory.
I want to know it because I have *Ubuntu 12.04 for Android* on my chrooted HTC One X. For *normal* file systems like a disk or a hard drive image it seems to be clear but how works a operating system loop device? My thought is, that a simualted disk is a *static* thing which has no own life but an operating system has it's *own* life with processes and threads which are running.

- Notices the kernel (here Android) that the loop device is an os image which needs a special mounting/handling? How is the native kernel in contact with the virtual os so that I can use an os within an os?
- Obviously it's mounted like a file system but communicates it with the kernel via the loop back adapter or has it nothing to do with that? (just the normal network communication)

I hope my problem isn't asked to complicated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to not be a native English speaker.  As written, I can not understand your question.  You might try editing the question to contain it in your native language, and others may be able to help translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop devices generally provides an interface to access a *file* as a *file-system*. In order to loop mount an image you have to place the image somewhere in your *real* file-systems, i.e. disk-partitions.

So while loop devices are virtual, the files they provides access to are not and those files occupy space.

When you add some data to the loop-mounted file-system the data is actually added to the image file, as if you are appending/inserting some bytes of data somewhere in a file. Loop device decides **where** to put those bytes. So the image file grows in size and deducts space from the hosting file-system.

To answer the question about how *OS within an OS* runs, it can be said that they either share kernels or use a hypervisor to emulate an encapsulated environment which translate another OS'es instructions to hosting OS'es instructions.